# save excel data to couchDB

Tags: json, excel, couchdb, data-export

I'm wondering if there is a tool that will save/push my MS Excel (or OO calc) data to CouchDB database. Googling didn't help a lot so I don't think there is an existing solution for this.

Excel -> json -> Curl to CouchDB would do the trick but I'm still hoping there is something out there that will save my time on programming this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the Excel data into a JSON file as Sam Bisbee suggests, you should be able to use the `tools/load.py` script from [couchdb-python](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/) to easily and quickly dump it into CouchDB without spending too much time writing your own. (Although I wouldn't think it would take that long to write your own...)

Check out [this blog post about loading/dumping JSON into/out of CouchDB](http://www.rossbates.com/2009/07/data-migration-for-couchdb/). The implementation uses Python.

Loading the JSON file should be as easy as:

```
./load.py –input=msg_db.json http://target-couchdb:5984/msg_db
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to pull the data itself out, then you've answered your own question, "Excel -> json -> Curl to CouchDB". A quick Google for "Excel to JSON converter" will pull up some answers for the first part of that journey.

Also, if you don't need to have CouchDB access the data in your spread sheet, then I'd suggest saving the Excel documents as attachments. More info on that here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments